# Form reactive return empty

Tags: angular, forms, reactive, angular10

Good Morning, I am trying to create a reactive form in **Angular 10**, but when i request the data to the form, it returns me an empty result

I don't understand why the form does not return the values if I'm doing the correct imports and I'm using the properties in the right way, please help me

this is the code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  formLogin: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private _builder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.formLogin = this._builder.group({
      user: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])],
      passwd: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(50)])]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

   onSubmitData() {
    console.log(this.formLogin.value);
  }



  /**
   * Este método no se puede modificar
   * */
  public redirectUsers(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/users/list');
  }

}
```

this is the Html code :

```
<div class="my-container">
  <form class="formLogin" [formGroup]="formLogin" (ngSubmit) ="onSubmitData()">

    <h3 class="titleLogin">Inicio de sesión</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login__email">Correo electrónico</label>
      <input formControlName="user" type="email" name="login__email" id="login__email">
    </div>
    <!-- <div *ngif="formLogin.get('email').hasError('email') && formLogin.get('email').touched">
      <span id="login__email-error">Error email</span>
    </div> -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login__password">Contraseña</label>
      <input formControlName="passwd" type="password" name="login__password" id="login__password">
    </div>

    <button class="btn-login" id="login__btn-login" [disabled]="formLogin.invalid">Iniciar sesión</button>
    <h1>{{formLogin.valid}}</h1>
  </form>
</div>
```

this is the  LoginModule code :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        LoginRoutingModule
    ]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

the return of my form is :

```
{user: "", passwd: ""}
```

Comment: The template button is calling `sendData(...)` but there is no such method in your `LoginComponent` class

Comment: sorry, that was becouse i was doing test, but it don't work either

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is to change the way that you're defining the Form :
By using FormGroup instead of FormBuilder

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  formLogin: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private readonly router: Router,
    private _builder: FormBuilder
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
this.formLogin = new FormGroup({
      user: new FormControl(["", Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)])]),
      passwd: new FormControl(["", Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.maxLength(50)])])
    });
  }

   onSubmitData() {
    console.log(this.formLogin.value);
  }



  /**
   * Este método no se puede modificar
   * */
  public redirectUsers(): void {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/users/list');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i solved my problem declaring the my component and importing formsModule and reactiveFormsModule in the module of my component,
i too discovered that i don´t could use ngIf or ngFor either, that was the clave for solved my problem.